# Get Whole Number for Power of 100 with PHP ( Question with PHP POW function )

Tags: php, math

That is my code below to get "100 power of 2 in PHP",

```
echo pow(2,100);
```

I would get the result as 1.2676506002282E+30, However, I wish to get a whole integer of the result.

How should I do it with PHP？

Comment: you want this `2^10 = 1024` ?

Comment: 2^100 , Kumar. 
but it will be converted to Scientific Expression due to its overflow, with PHP. pow() function.

Comment: I don't think so, CBroe.
Appreciate your answer anyway. 
The solution is to use another function in PHP. (Ex: gmp_pow() or bcpow().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if by accurate, you want to have the exact value of 2  to the power of 100 that is equal to 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376,

you can simply use

```
echo number_format(pow(2,100));
```

**Update**: like @Olivier said in comments, `number_format` does not return the exact results in some cases, so be careful in using that.

Comment: @Jim Be aware that `pow(2,100)` returns a float, not an integer. Which means you have no guarantee to get an exact result when you do that (although in this particular case, it does give the expected result).

Comment: @Jim For example, `number_format(pow(3,40))` gives a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by "accurate" you mean you want to get an exact integer. You will have to use additional library for working with big integers. GMP for example will work for what you need. It's is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers.

Here is an example for the specific question:

```
<?php
    $pow = gmp_pow("2", 100);
    echo gmp_strval($pow);
?>
```

It will not work directly. You will have to first open php.ini and uncomment the "extension=gmp" line.

And that's not the only solution. There are more libraries available as variants for doing that.

Comment: Exactly!  Appreciate, Philip. 
I try with another solution, 
```echo bcpow(2,100);```

Comment: GMP is much faster and that's why I prefer it.

Comment: For example on my machine (old 8 core AMD FX CPU) 10k gmp_pow calls with different arguments take 0.2s while 10k bcpow calls with different arguments take 28.0s. This is a HUGE difference.